# Error 500 on /projects when doing first time install of directus

Tags: php, directus

I've installed the current version of directus on my VPS (Debian 10, PHP 7.3, Apache 2.4.38).

When running the browser-based install, an error appears in the /logs saying:

[2020-02-27 20:31:59] api[].ERROR: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/clients/client0/web16/web/vendor/symfony/translation-contracts/TranslatorTrait.php:44

For me, it sounds like if it was a wrong PHP version, but PHP 7.3 is running.

I don't know whether this is important, but after ignoring this, on the page where you enter the database connection parameter, the POST to /server/projects returns with Error 500 "Internal Server Error".

I cannot find any log entry.

- How can I find the reason for the 500?
- Is it possible to configure the application without the browser-based installation?

**Edit**
Switched back from `master` to `v8.5.5` and in this source code, there is a trans function:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function trans(?string $id, array $parameters = [], string $domain = null, string $locale = null): string
{
    if (null === $id || '' === $id) {
        return '';
    }

    if (!isset($parameters['%count%']) || !is_numeric($parameters['%count%'])) {
        return strtr($id, $parameters);
    }
```

So there is indeed a type `?string`.

My PHP version should be able to handle this, IMO. But before, I had Debian 9 with PHP 7.0 where I had the same problem and which was the reason to upgrade Debian from 9 to 10.

Is it possible that a compile-cache from Debian 9 is still present?

But I suppose this is not the main problem. My problem is that I receive an error 500 and besides the 500-log-entry in apache error.log, there is nothing I can see to diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 2):

A handy way to find syntax errors when error reporting and logs don't yield anything is to try and run the script through command line using the lint flag, e.g.

```
php -l path/to/file.php
```

Comment: Output is: `No syntax errors detected in TranslatorTrait.php`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @hgoebl No worries. I'd maybe also check that your php cli is using the same version of php as the apache module? As you say it sounds like a php version issue, as nullable types were introduced in 7.1

Answer (score 1):

`TranslatorTrait.php` seems to be corrupted, because line `#44` actually should be:

```
public function trans($id, array $parameters = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
```

So obviously, there should be no unexpected `?`. Try to refresh `composer` dependencies with:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
```

And then:

```
composer clearcache && composer install
```